# Git sees to many changes within branches while making pull request

Tags: javascript, git, github

While working on a project we have faced a problem with git.
I have a branch "D", which is a feature branch. 
Then I have a branch "A" which is my master.

I have merged `"A"` into `"D"` but git sends me a message: "Already up to date" when there are some changes at the "D" branch.

When I was creating branches, every next one depends on the previous one. So the flow was like `A -> B -> C -> D`.
Since branch "C" I can see on my pull request that 46 files are changed while only 4 to 5 files were changed.

I think it's important to mention that while I was working on Ubuntu and there were some problems with files permissions and I did `sudo chown` command on some files.

While doing `git fsck --full` I can see the output:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (1072/1072), done.
dangling tree 1c706090df93f04b78e35d94ef9a55af86daa444
```

Comment: So from your story I understood that you created B branch from A, and made some changes, then you create C branch from B, what next? Do you trying to merge C branch into A? What are purpose of those branches B C D?

Comment: All the previous branches are merged into A, one by one in order of creation.

Comment: Why did you add the `fsck` output? I mean, what is the (supposed) relevance to the present problem?

Comment: Also, the title does not match the described problem. It's even the contrary. Maybe clarify?

Comment: Are you working along? You telling that you see some changes, so may be someone did actually updated those files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+merge+says+branch+already+up+to+date

Comment: Can you clarify, you did changes to several files (4-5) in C, then you committed, then you pulled and saw those 46 files changed. Looks like there was some commit to C and you need to merge your changes with that one. If my understanding of the process wrong, tell exact steps of your workflow, like "created branch A", "made changes to A", "pushed changes to A", "created branch B from A"....

Comment: The flow is pretty simple.  
I have A - master branch, than I can create feature branches from A - > B. Than I merge B into A, than on a branch B I create branch C and merge branch C into A etc.

Comment: I think it is wrong pattern, you always should merge branch into branch that is parent. So you need to merge your C into B and then B into A and not C into A. Better to create feature branch from main branch so B, C and D should be created from A, then you have no problems to merge them back into A.

Comment: When the C feature is based on the B feature, but B is not reviewed and not merged into A, how can I create C branch from A??

Not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The message git sends you means that there are no changes in A that are absent in D. Thus the "up-to-date" message.

If you wanted the changes in D to be applied in your master branch (A), you'd have to merge the other way

```
git checkout A
git merge D
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that "A" has any new changes, that are not in "D" branch? If here is no new changes, "A" commit history is the part of "D" commit history, and it is "Already up-to-date" because here is no to change in "D" commit history. If you want to merge youtr feature in master, you may merge "D" into "A".